# simply mute on questions of this sort, and hundreds like them

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "and hundreds like them" refer to "and hundreds of questions like these questions of this sort"?

> Is there anything else that we can infer about him on the basis of his behavior? Was he popular in school Was he rich or was he poor? Was he of low or high intelligence? His actions leave no clue at all. Did he have a college education? Did he have a bright future as a mechanical engineer? His behavior is simply mute on questions of this sort, **and hundreds like them**.

> Source: The End of Faith by Sam Harris page 12

Comment: It's poorly worded. First, it's a tautology because "of this sort" already expresses "like them," which makes the phrase "and hundreds like them" very confusing. Second, "behavior" can't answer these questions or questions of this sort. Behavior can speak to certain things, like character, but it can't answer specific questions like, "Did he have a college education?" So of course it's mute. What it should say is, "He is simply mute on these questions, and hundreds like them." That would mean he hasn't answered any of the five questions listed, nor answered hundreds of others similar to them.

Comment: @Benjamin, changing from "his behaviour" to "he" would change the meaning.  It is about the impossibility of  inferring facts about the person from his behaviour. So "mute" is not about literal speech.  Not a tautology, since you can't know that there are "hundreds" of other similar questions from the phrase "of this sort".  I don't find the meaning confusing at all.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Technically it _could_ mean "hundreds **of sorts** like them" (he is mute on _hundreds of sorts_ of issues) but I'm pretty sure you're right: it's just poorly worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is right.

The author says that his (the suicide bomber's) behaviour is mute on these questions and many other questions.  That is we can't infer the answers to these questions from the actions of the suicide bomber.